# Need to change the display name of multiple buttons with variables

Tags: javascript, html, variables, video

I have a video that automatically starts playing. And I have a button:

```
<button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button>
```

JS:

```
function playPause() { 
if (myVideo.paused) 
    myVideo.play(); 
else 
    myVideo.pause(); 
}
```

And I want him to be named "Pause" when I open the page and he changes his name to "Play" when the video is paused and "Pause" when the video is being played.

I have this other button (similar to this one) that acts like this:
When the video is loaded the video window size is 480p and when I press the button "HD" it changes the video window size to 1280p and its own name to "SD" (for when I go to change back to 480p window) (user 1533609 ankit helped me here):

```
<button onclick="goHD(this)">HD</button>
```

JS:

```
function goHD(el)   {
if (myVideo.width != 1280){
    myVideo.width = 1280
    el.innerHTML = "SD"
    }
else{
    myVideo.width = 720
    el.innerHTML = "HD";
}
}
```

This is one is working great in my code but I don't see what I have to do to be able to do the exact same thing in the "Pause/play" button.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: try to get away from using `onclick` attributes, it'll bite you in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<button onclick="playPause(this)">Play/Pause</button>
```

And

```
function playPause(btn) { 
if (myVideo.paused) {
    myVideo.play();
    btn.innerHTML = "play" 
} else {
    myVideo.pause(); 
    btn.innerHTML = "pause" 
}
}
```

See an example: https://jsfiddle.net/j82447k5/

Does it help you?

Comment: It did help a lot! Thank you :D Just to understand better what is the difference between using el.innerHTML and btn.innerHTML and how I use one over the other. Is there a good explanation online?

Comment: btn and el are just variable names. You can put anything you want as a variable name. Important here is keep the reference for the keyword this : onclick="playPause(this);" ok?

Comment: oh ok :) And if I want to change that variable from another function: Changing the "Pause" button to "start" after pressing a "stop" button I have (stop button: sets video timer to 0 and pauses the video so it doesnt autostart). Do I just add btn.innerHTML = "Play" to the end of the script? (It isnt working as it is) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery, then you can change the button text easliy by using the `text()` function on `this` object which signifies the button.

If video is paused, then play it and change the text to `Pause` and vice verse. Updated code will be:

```
function playPause() { 
    if (myVideo.paused) {
       myVideo.play(); 
       $(this).text('Pause');
    }
    else{
        $(this).text('Play'); 
        myVideo.pause(); 
    }
}
```

If you are using javascript only, then you can use `textContent/innerText` properties (browser-dependant):

Updated HTML:

```
<button type="button" onclick="playPause(this);">Play/Pause</button>
```

Updated JS:

```
function playPause(myBtn) { 

    if (myVideo.paused)
    {
        myVideo.play(); 
        myBtn.innerHTML = "Pause";
    }
    else {
        myVideo.pause(); 
        myBtn.innerHTML = "Play";
    }
}
```

See the fiddle: "https://jsfiddle.net/h7qb1b58/2/"

Comment: Thanks! I am sorry I forgot to mention that I wasnt going to be able to use Jquery even though I wanted to.

Comment: No problem, hope that answer helped :)

Comment: I am going to start with jquery next week so it will help me :D Thanks

Comment: My answer contained javascript implementation as well in case you didn't notice :)

Comment: Oh. I was in such a rush at the time that when I saw the jquery code I jumped right in to the comments. I am such a fool... I ended up using the same code :) About that... What if I want to use/change that variable in another script? Do I just add myBtn.innerHTML = "Play" to the end of the script? or do I have to do anything else? e.g. Stop button (sets the video to 0 secs), onclick changes name of  "Pause" to "Play" (to start the video)... Is that possible? It is not working properly for me :(

Comment: Or... When the video gets to the end, change the name of "Pause" to "Play" to start the video again.

Comment: You can use button element in another script if that script is included in that  particular html page. Here basically "myBtn" refers to the current "element"  which was stored in "this" variable sent via the "onclick="playPause(this);" . So in another script you can pass the "this"(reference to the button) and then use innerHTML there using the reference of" this" passed as function parameter.

Comment: So, what I understand is: I need to start another <script></script>; create the function myVideo.onended = function() {
    this.innerHTML = "Play";
}; ? Sorry, I am bad at this :(